# Unable to run "sdl-config"

Tags: pygame

I'm new to Pi and Linux, and I'm using the Pi Zero W with a fresh version of Raspbian installed. I'm trying to get PyGame installed on the Pi so that I can work on a project. When I run the command

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pygame $ python setup.py
```

This is the output:

```
No Arguments Given, Perform Default Install? [Y/n]y

WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using UNIX configuration...

Hunting dependencies...
sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
```

What does this mean in terms of the Pi? What can I do to fix this (some terminal commands would be great, I have no idea how to use the Debian Package Tracking System)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Be sure to take the tour to see how this works and to earn a badge:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An easy way to find the package providing a given file is `apt-file`; you can also do much the same thing [online from here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents).  First you need to install apt-file:

```
> sudo apt install apt-file
```

After that:

```
> apt-file search "sdl-config"
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/bin/sdl-config
libsdl1.2-dev: /usr/bin/sdl-config
libsdl1.2-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/sdl-config.1.gz
lush-library: /usr/share/lush/packages/sdl/sdl-config.lsh
```

You are almost certainly looking for something in a `bin` directory with no suffix, since this seems to be an [in `$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) executable (since it was "not found" using only a base name), which probably excludes the first entry (since that directory is not in a standard `$PATH`).  A more fine tuned way to do this search would be `apt-file search "*/bin/sdl-config"`, which would give you only those two entries.

Anyway, most likely it is the `-dev` package, so:

```
sudo apt install libsdl1.2-dev
```

Should do it.

Comment: "sudo apt install apt-file"  should be extended with " && sudo apt update" to get the package cache updated, otherwise the next step doesn't work.

Comment: If the call to `apt install...` worked, then there is already a valid cache.  You might as well say that *any and all* `apt` commands should be preceded by `apt update` to work "properly" since the information in the cache may become outdated at any point.  In fact, even doing that you are at risk of using an outdate cache because it may have become so milliseconds after `apt update` completes.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-file search "sdl-config"
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/bin/sdl-config
libsdl1.2-dev: /usr/bin/sdl-config
libsdl1.2-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/sdl-config.1.gz
lush-library: /usr/share/lush/packages/sdl/sdl-config.lsh
```

If you get more than one resulting package from your search, you may inspect the found packages for a description with:

```
apt-cache show <package-name>
```

`libsdl1.2-dev` has been chosen by the user, because `emscripten` and `lush-library` may pull several other packages from Java or Lisp. Thats a lot of extra stuff you may never use on your Pi.

Comment: I don't see any added value in this answer. The existing answer already explains what package the OP needs and how to use `apt-file search` to find it.